# Admin Controller for module in prestahop

Tags: controller, admin, prestashop

while developing a module, I was stuck in problem of how to redirect page from tpl file to admin controller in Prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript redirect:

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript/506004)

Just do not forget to pass the token to the template and pass it.

Comment: thank you for answering but I need to call it using prestashop methods only.

Comment: There's no PrestaShop method for redirecting from tpl file.

Comment: May be you mean to link to another admin controller? From Front Office template or from BackOffice template?

Comment: From back office template I simply wants to call a custom admin controller of a module. With jquery also it is showing an error?